# Automate generating column charts from data in Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

So I have some data that I currently import to Power Bi and then create a column chart that shows some averages. I was looking into Power Automate and not sure I understand it correctly. I want to import that data in Power Bi and when something is clicked like a button or something, basically create a flow that generates that chart. Something like what I am doing in Excel with macros. Is this possible? I am new to Power Bi and Power Automate so not sure if there such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the tables and charts created in your PowerBI report:
If you use a connector to upload your data from a data source, “refresh” will update those tables and charts automatically by reloading from the source (no need for Power Automate).

For the “end-user” interaction of your PowerBI report:

For some button actions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-buttons?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Also, you can integrate Power Automate flows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-automate-visual?tabs=powerbi-desktop